# Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Moq.Mock<System.Data.Entity.DbContext>' to 'System.Data.Entity.DbContext'

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit, moq

on my mocked context I have the following:

```
 var mockContext = new Mock<DbContext>();
 mockContext.Setup(c => c.Set<Track>()).Returns(mockSet.Object);
```

an when I try to create mocked object for my repository I use the following code

```
EfRepository<Track> _efTrackRepository = new EfRepository<Shelf>(mockContext);
```

and I get the following error, is there any way I can solve this out?

error:

Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Moq.Mock<System.Data.Entity.DbContext>' to 'System.Data.Entity.DbContext'

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should use `mockContext.Object`

```
//
// Summary:
//     Exposes the mocked object instance.
public virtual T Object { get; }
```